# OAuth2 Authentication at Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am struggling to redirect to Azure AD endpoint (MS Login page) for authentication from `API Management`.
I tried `OAuth2/Openidconnect` in `APIM` but not succeeded.
What is the use of OAuth2 in APIM? Is it only for testing from Developer Portal?

Comment: This tutorial may help you, please refer to it: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/configure-openid-connect-in-azure-api-management2

Comment: This also says to check from Developer portal (Step 21). Using Validate-jwt send UnAuthorize response if user is not Authenticated. I am wondering what is the use of OpenIdConnect/OAuth2/Identity options given to configure in APIM.

Comment: Did you do it successfully in developer portal ?

Comment: yes. From Developer Portal it is working as expected

Answer (score 0):

It ensure that only valid users have access, and they can only access resources to which they're entitled.

In order to use Azure API Management's interactive Developer Console with such APIs, the service allows you to configure your service instance to work with your OAuth 2.0 enabled API.

Follow the doc for more info. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-oauth2